# 'Firebase init' command didn't create package.json, index.js and function folder

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I’m now trying to create a tutorial app for my Google Home but I faced some trouble. According to [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/first-app#build_fulfillment), I finished following steps of Build fulfillment.

```
1.Download and install Node.js.
2.npm install -g firebase-tools
3.firebase login
4-1.mkdir sillynamemaker
4-2.cd sillynamemaker
4-3.firebase init
5.select Functions:…
6.select action project(silllynamemaker-***)
7.firebase init
```

But after step 7, there were only ‘firebase.json’ in current folder, so I couldn’t see functions folder, package.json and index.js.

My console log is below.

```
$ node -v
v8.6.0
$ npm --version
5.3.0
$ firebase --version
3.13.1

$ firebase init
You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory: ~/ghome/sillynamemaker

? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to setup for this folder? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices. 
⚠  You have have not selected any features. Continuing will simply associate this folder with a Firebase project. Press Ctrl + C if you want to start over.

=== Project Setup
First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

? Select a default Firebase project for this directory: SillyNameMaker (sillynamemaker-*****)

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!
```

I'm really glad if someone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you selected "functions"?  It should say "Functions Setup" and then "A functions directory will be created in your project with a Node.js
package pre-configured. Functions can be deployed with firebase deploy."  This works for me.

Comment: Hi Doug. After reading your comment, I found that I didn't just press space bar.. And now it works. Thank you so much for your advice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must select features you want to initialize by using the arrow keys and spacebar -- none are on by default. See the error message in your pasted log:

```
⚠  You have have not selected any features. Continuing will simply associate this folder with a Firebase project. Press Ctrl + C if you want to start over.
```

You can also run `firebase init functions` to specifically initialize only functions.

Comment: Hi, Michael. Thank your for your advice. As you mentioned, I didn't just press spacebar to select features.. :( Now it all works. I'll be more careful to read a guide. 

Thanks!

Comment: even when i press the spacebar and use enter to select a feature, it did not work either, what solved it for me whats `firebase init functions`